# Conditionally override <p:hotkey> depending on whether <p:dialog> is visible

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, facelets, hotkeys

I have a general include Facelet with hotkeys configured via `<p:hotkey>` (like Alt+S, Alt+C, and more). This Facelet can be included in among others another Facelet representing a `<p:dialog>`. However, this dialog has the same hotkeys configured for another purposes specific to the dialog. The hotkeys definied in the include Facelet are conflicting with this.

How can I configure the hotkeys definied in the dialog Facelet to work only when the dialog is opened and the hotkeys definied in the general include Facelet to work only when the dialog is closed?